# Brother Mine! Missing

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, cipher, lateral-thinking

So, just the other day, i was sitting outside trying to piece some sort of puzzle together, when my brother called.  He had this rather strange message for me.

"Mostly it's you who did it boy.... for every time his despair was unto you. Call this phone number, probably, to get information:
+353758960391"

I later received a message from an unknown number, claiming to be my brother. It stated that I needed to find where he was, asking me to "find the source".

Hint(I saw this in my dream the night i got the phone call):

> _ _ _ . _ _ .

Hint 2:

> The first hint is related to the contents of the call

Hint 3:

> The first hint deals with the number

Thats practically the answer now

Comment: rot18(Zvkvat uvag 6 jvgu gur ahzore, bar bcgvba gung bppheerq gb zr jnf gb cnve gur ahzoref ba n qnfu naq yrnir gur ahzore fvathyne ba n qbg. Gur bayl ernfba guvf hayvxryl fpranevb jneenagf cbfgvat vf orpnhfr vg rknpgyl pbafhzrf rirel ahzore: 80 82 03 4 15 84 6. Fgvyy uvtuyl hayvxryl, naq V pbhyqa'g ghea vg va gb nalguvat hfrshy, ohg V gubhtug V'q cbfg vg whfg va pnfr vg urycf fbzrbar ryfr bhg).

Comment: Try using that somehow

Answer (score 3):

The phone numbers country code, could suggest that he is somewhere in

> Ireland, which has 353 as a code.

The first hint could be read as morse code - and depending how you space it, it could be

> _ _ (space) _. (space)  _ _. - which is MNG - which could be MANGO without the vocals.

If my first hint is read correctly, it would suggest that he is somewhere in

> Blanchardstown, Dublin, Ireland - which is the address of MANGO fashion in Ireland

If it is morse code, it could be any one of these letters though..

> MKN, MKTE, MNG, MNME, MNTN, MNTTE, MTAN, MTATE, MTEG, MTEME, MTETN, MTETTE, MTP,    MTWE, MYE, OAN, OATE, OEG, OEME, OETN, OETTE, OP, OWE, TGG, TGME, TGTN, TGTTE, TMAN,    TMATE, TMEG, TMEME, TMETN, TMETTE, TMP, TMWE, TQN, TQTE, TTKN, TTKTE, TTNG, TTNME,    TTNTN, TTNTTE, TTTAN, TTTATE, TTTEG, TTTEME, TTTETN, TTTETTE, TTTP, TTTWE, TTYE,

Comment: Dont treat the number like a phone number. Also, see hint 2. The morse attempt is correct in ideology, but its not npstf

Comment: npstf? what does that mean=

Comment: @Stender - npstf is a word encoded in ROT25 (or ROT-1, since it makes the math easier)

Answer (score 2):

Well, following my idea I was able to get to this:

> http://confluence.org/confluence.php?visitid=4359

It's unlikely a correct answer, but here's my logic nonetheless.

> Using the pattern of _ _ _ . _ _ . on the number 353758960391, and assuming that a dash means to take two numbers and a dot to take one, I come up with 35 37 58 9 60 39 1. Converting the two digit numbers to characters via the ASCII table and leaving the single digit numbers alone, I end up with 57X9``91. Assuming that these are lat and longitude, I get 57N x 9W with a `91 left over. 91 minutes is not valid, so it must mean something else. The altitude at that point is roughly 90', which sort of tracks with the 91 left over. Not sure why a backtick is used as a separator, but that is just one more reason to think this is not the answer.
>  On the plus side, I learned about visiting confluence points, so there's that.

Comment: Great going! Youre halfway there. The answer is not right, and similarly not the interpretation of what you decoded. The num has more to do with the message than place

Answer (score 0):

Is he in

> China? Specifically, [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B022'32.9%22N+96%C2%B002'20.8%22E/@35.3767382,96.0371715,462m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.3758!4d96.0391)?
> Reasoning: I couldn't find a valid phone number from the number provided above, so I thought that it could be coordinates instead, just combined. So I took the first six numbers as a coordinate and the last six as a coordinate and plugged them in. However, there are problems with this, such as this is in the middle of nowhere. I thought your hint was morse code, but it returns TTTETTE, which just looks like gibberish.

Comment: Not there. What could the phone number be telling you?

Comment: It is the cubar vaqvpngbe bs Verynaq

Comment: @guillau4 no. Thats not the intent of the number

Comment: does it relate to `OP`